# underline the clicked text element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a list of text elements that I want to underline when clicked. If I add the text decoration to the `tabText` then obviously it is applied to all items. How can I make sure that the when I click on another tab, the underline from the previous tab gets removed?

Is there any way I can add or remove items from the style element upon clicking on an item?

```
//onPress={() => {}}>
const tabs = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Alle List',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'Second',
  },
];
export const Tab: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.tabView}>
      {tabs.map((item: any) => (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.tabText}>{item.text}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabView: {
    paddingTop: moderateScale(15),
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(20),
    paddingRight: moderateScale(20),
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  tabText: {
    color: 'white',
    paddingBottom: moderateScale(10),
    //textDecorationLine: 'underline'
  },
});
```

Codesandbox (with tabText items as an array too):

https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/shallow-watermelon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use useState to save the selected index and then apply another style based on the selected index. Here is a quick modification to your script and the snack link is at the end.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const tabs = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'All Friends',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'Second',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'Third',
  },
];
export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(null)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.tabView}>
        {tabs.map((item: any, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>setSelected(index)}>
          <View>
            <Text style={[styles.tabText,selected===index?styles.selected:null]}>{item.text}</Text>
          </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabView: {
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  tabText: {
    color: 'black',
    paddingBottom: 10,
  },
  selected: {
    textDecorationLine: 'underline'
  },
});
```

https://snack.expo.io/@saachitech/da6280

Comment: Is it possible to style the underline too? For instance, I added a color to it but I want to increase it's height or maybe increase the distance between the underline and the text. ```textDecorationColor: 'green```,

Comment: perhaps use ```textUnderlinePosition: 'under'```, here is more info https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-underline-position/

Comment: Updated Snack with border-bottom styles

Answer (score 0):

You can add different styles for your tab depending on active route

```
<Text style={[(this.props.activeRouteName == route.routeName) ? styles.tabActiveText: styles.tabText]}>{item.text}</Text>    

And then in the styles

tabActiveText: {
    color: 'white',
    paddingBottom: moderateScale(10),
    textDecorationLine: 'underline'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. There's no 'activeRoute' right now. This is just plain text. And there's no this. property here either since I am not using classes